# BeautifulSoup Python If the text is in the same div as another text

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to check if the text e.g.: "Recommended" is in the same div as the text "Product".
The structure of the HTML file is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Product Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div1">
<div class="div2">
<div class="divInside">
    Recommended
</div>
<div class="above">
    <div class="under"></div>
</div>
<div class="pct"></div>
<div class="prod">
    Product
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's just an example HTML file to show my problem but as you can see both texts are in the same div with `div2` class and they are in their own divs as well. So how can I check if both texts are present in a `div2` class div tag?

Comment: Do you know ahead of time what those two texts are or are you trying to see if `<div class="div2">` has any two different text elements?

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes, I know these two texts ahead of time. I just wanna check if div with `div2` class has both of them or just 1 of them.

Answer (score 0):

For every element in your HTML DOM, you can get all children of the elements as **lists**, then check if they occur in the same list (there are many ways to do that - for instance, turn such a list into a set, then compare their lenghts). Repeat this for every children until the child has no further children.

Comment: I don't really get that.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to try something along these lines (in this case, with CSS selectors):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
data = """your html above"""
soup = bs(data,'lxml')
targets = ['Recommended', 'Product']
print(targets == list(soup.select('div.div2')[0].stripped_strings))
#or
print(targets == list(soup.select_one('div.div2').stripped_strings))
```

Output in either case:

```
True
```